# Prevent Flash from using webcam and microphone?

Tags: security, flash, webcam, microphone

How do you configure Flash to not allow access to [webcam and mic](https://askubuntu.com/q/10415)?

I'm currently primarily interested in this for Chrome, but if the solution is different for other browsers, please list it as well.

Comment: You just made me crash my browser....  :-(

Comment: @JanC: Ouch, how'd that happen?

Comment: I guess there is a good reason why I have Flash disabled normally...  :P

Comment: @JanC: The Flash plugin also crashed for me when I was experimenting with this on a YouTube video (the first place I thought of to load Flash)... but at least Chrome sandboxed it. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply open the Macromedia [settings manager](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager02.html) and select "Always Deny" in the "Global Privacy Settings panel".

On a side note: this page is accessible from all browsers and those settings will be used by all browsers.

Comment: This is where you're taken when selecting the option JanC mentions, thanks.

Comment: (I'll have to wait until tonight to get more upvotes.)

Comment: I don't care about rep points. :-) As long the question is answered, everything's fine.

Answer (score 2):

*(An expansion on [JanC's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10417/prevent-flash-from-using-webcam-and-microphone/10422#10422) which wouldn't fit in a comment.)*

Right-click on a Flash applet and select "Settings..." to control just that site:

[image: Flash settings screenshot]

The "Global Settings..." option controls all sites.  It appears disabling it globally still allows you to enable per-site, as that's what I did for the above screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the right-click menu if you click on any flash applet that will bring you to a special applet on Adobe's site where you can configure that.

It also seems like the only options are "always deny" or "always ask"...